# Import XML into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, xml, database, import

I'm new to coding, trying to create a database from an XML file which is a list of industries, company names and symbols. I've seen a few examples of a PHP code that imports the data into MySQL which looked something like:

```
<?php

$url ="http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.industry%20where%20id%20in%20(select%20industry.id%20from%20yahoo.finance.sectors)&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); //getting url contents

$data = curl_exec ($ch); //execule curl request
curl_close($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

$con=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); //connect to server
mysql_select_db("symbol_list", $con) or die(mysql_error()); //select database

foreach ($xml -> item as $row) {
    $industry = $row -> industry;
    $company = $row -> name;
    $symbol = $row -> symbol;

// perform sql query


$sql = "INSERT INTO 'symbols_xml' ('industry', 'company', 'symbol')"
    . "VALUES ('$industry', '$company', '$symbol')";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    echo 'MySQL ERROR';
} else {

    echo 'SUCCESS';
}


                            }

?>
```

However, because the XML is formatted like this:

```
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:count="215" yahoo:created="2015-03-02T20:58:57Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
<results>
<industry id="112" name="Agricultural Chemicals">
    <company name="Adarsh Plant Protect Ltd" symbol="ADARSHPL.BO"/>
    <company name="African Potash Ltd" symbol="AFPO.L"/>
    ......
</industry>
<industry id="132" name="Aluminum">
    <company name="AEI Corp Ltd" symbol="A18.SI"/>
    <company name="Alcoa Inc" symbol="AA.BA"/>
    <company name="Alcoa Inc" symbol="AA.MX"/>
    ......
```

My PHP code above is unable to recognise the values...
Is there any way to import the attributes (industry name, company name and symbol) so that it looks something like:

```
    #| Industry  | Company    | Symbol
    -|----------- ------------ -------
    1| Aluminium | Alcoa Inc. | AA.BA
```

and so on..

I just recently started learning PHP and databases so please forgive me if this is a noobish question that wasted your time. xD

Thanks.

Comment: much simpler code to do. PHP Import XML File Into Database  -   http://www.kvcodes.com/2017/04/php-import-xml-file-database/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were actually not very far.

In order to fetch an attribute, you can do it in two ways :

1. Access it as if the node was an array `$node['attributeName']`
2. Use a method named attributes(), and you could also do : `$node->attributes()->attributeName;`

Here is your code updated :

```
<?php

$url ="http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.industry%20where%20id%20in%20(select%20industry.id%20from%20yahoo.finance.sectors)&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); //getting url contents

$data = curl_exec ($ch); //execule curl request
curl_close($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

$con=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); //connect to server
mysql_select_db("symbol_list", $con) or die(mysql_error()); //select database

foreach ($xml->results->industry as $industryNode) 
{
    foreach ($industryNode->company as $companyNode) 
    {
        $industry = (string) $industryNode['name'];
        $company = (string) $companyNode['name'];
        $symbol = (string) $companyNode['symbol'];

        // perform sql query
        $sql = "INSERT INTO 'symbols_xml' ('industry', 'company', 'symbol')"
            . "VALUES ('$industry', '$company', '$symbol')";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if (!$result) 
        {        
            echo 'MySQL ERROR';
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo 'SUCCESS';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This "node" stuff seems to work because now I'm at least getting a "MySQL ERROR" msg from an "if" statement. Any idea wht could be wrong with mysql_query?

Comment: Do an `echo $sql;` inside the 2nd foreach loop and add `echo die(mysql_error());` inside if the `if(!$result)` statement. You can also copy paste the query that is outputted into your favorite mysql client and see the error.

Comment: Awesome, thanks again. The problem was wrong syntax - shouldn't have put ' around column names in         $sql = "INSERT INTO 'symbols_xml' (industry, company, symbol)"